# Incorrect Mime Type of uploaded file

Tags: html, iis, file-upload

My html is like this:

```
<input type="file" id="myfile" />
```

My javascript code is:

```
var myfile = $('#myfile');
```

When trying to upload a `.doc` file and debugging I can see the type: `type: "application/msword"`

When doing the same but this time for a `.rar` when debugging the type is an empty string. Strange because in my local IIS I have correct type and also in Web.Config. I also tested with `.abc` and same problem.

Tested with Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge.

Any idea ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Content-Type of a file upload is determined by the **browser** not the server, so your IIS settings are irrelevant.

Short of using the File API to read the file and using XHR or fetch to send it (with a whole lot of content-type sniffing in the middle), the content-type the browser picks is beyond your control.

Comment: So If I need to block user upload of some file type (ex: .rar) do I need to extract the file extension to check (javascript code) ? I know I must perform security check server side but I would like to avoid user to upload some file type immediately. Thanks.